# Using PrintWriter for file IO

Tags: java, file, file-io

Ok so I'm about to start pulling my hair out. I thought file input was a little tricky, but oh man then there is file output. I am trying to write an array of coordinates stored in an object to a file. In C++ this was easy peasy, but for the love of God I cannot figure this out.

```
public static void outFile(int intersectionsIndex, Coordinate arg[], Coordinate avgPoint) {

    File file = new File("resource/result.txt");
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < intersectionsIndex) {
        writer.print(arg[i].getX());
        writer.print(" ");
        writer.println(arg[i].getY());
        i++;
    }
    writer.print("Predicted Coordinate: ");
    writer.print(avgPoint.getX());
    writer.print(" ");
    writer.println(avgPoint.getY());
    writer.close();

    return;
}
```

I am constantly getting the same error no matter what method of IO I use. I followed some posts on here with similar problems but to no avail. Any suggestions or other methods? I am probably missing something basic.

Edit: sorry error is

```
Error:(83, 30) java: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

Which is the "PrintWriter writer = newPrintWriter(file); line.

UPDATE: Problem solved. Working code below:

```
public static void outFile(int intersectionsIndex, Coordinate arg[], Coordinate avgPoint) throws Exception{

    File file = new File("resource/result.txt");
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < intersectionsIndex) {
        writer.print(arg[i].getX());
        writer.print(" ");
        writer.println(arg[i].getY());
        i++;
    }
    writer.print("Predicted Coordinate: ");
    writer.print(avgPoint.getX());
    writer.print(" ");
    writer.println(avgPoint.getY());
    writer.close();

    return;
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: You have a (potential) infinite while loop in the middle of your code, perhaps you meant to increment `i`?

Comment: does file exists at correct location?

Comment: It does help if you tell us the error...

Comment: Would you please paste your errors?

Comment: oops error is updated.

Comment: exception says a lot.

Comment: @CPUTerminator yup thanks. But previous problem persists.

Comment: @Braj I've tried using try/catch to resolve but nope. Also I'm very new to Java (if you couldn't already tell)

Comment: Have a look at my answer.

Comment: The compiler has told you exactly what you need to do: "`must be caught or declared to be thrown`".

Comment: Never declare a `method` as `throws Exception`. This is lazy and extremely bad practice. It forces the practice of `catch(Exception e)` which is an appalling abuse of exception handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the error that you get is actually a compile-time error, not a runtime error.

The contructor `PrintWriter(File)` declares a checked `FileNotFoundException` in its signature, therefore you either need to surround its invocation with `try ... catch` block, or to declare that exception in `throws` declaration of your method to catch it later.

**See also:**

- [Lesson: Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Answer (score 1):

Always try to avoid absolute path because the same code might not work on another system.

I suggest you to place it inside the project under `resources` folder.

You can try any one based on file location.

```
// Read from resources folder parallel to src in your project
File file1 = new File("resources/results.txt");

// Read from src/resources folder
File file2 = new File(getClass().getResource("/resources/results.txt").toURI());
```

---

You might forget to increment `i` in `while` loop. Add `i++` to avoid infinite loop.

Try

```
while (i++ < intersectionsIndex) {...}
```

OR

```
while (i < intersectionsIndex) {
   ...
   i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually used to have it in resources, but then got here after fidgeting with it.

Comment: @DavidConrad but to write as well you have to get it first.

Comment: Uh, you can write to a file that doesn't exist yet, in which case the file gets created. I suspect we're talking past one another.